# Why is this not working in Firefox but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

When i click the row on IE it calls the hello() method and works fine but not in Firefox. I'm suspecting this line

```
tr align="left" bgcolor="eeeeee" style="padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;">
```

because when i remove it it works sort of

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function hello(){
    alert('hello');
    }
</script>
<span style="" onclick="hello();"
    onmouseover="this.children[0].style.backgroundColor='#D8EEEE'; this.children[1].style.backgroundColor='#D8EEEE';"
    onmouseout="this.children[0].style.backgroundColor=''; this.children[1].style.backgroundColor='';">
<tr align="left" bgcolor="eeeeee">
    style="padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;">
    <td class="blueFont" style="font-weight: bold; <%=style%>">
```

I've tried removing the semicolon from onclick already

Comment: Please tell what doesn't work and show what errors you are getting in Firefox. Also, you should show the rendered final HTML code, not the ASP source

Comment: I sort of reformatted your code. I'm saying "sort of", because there is definitely something missing in there. There's a style appearing from nowhere for instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML is invalid, a `<span>` element can't contain `<tr>` element. Firefox and Internet Explorer are trying to recover from this in different ways.

IIRC, Internet Explorer will wrap the `<tr>` with the `<span>` anyway, while Firefox will move the `<span>` so it is after the end of the `<table>`. As a result, the child element of the span that you are trying to reach doesn't exist.

Start with [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/). You can use the `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>` elements to mark sections of a table.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've got a 'tr' inside a 'span' ?